# how to print a Map Object?

Tags: c++, object, printing, dictionary

sorry if my question is to newbish, but i cant find a solution.

i have a class named Transition that have a map called inNext, and i want to print this Transition object, but i get an error about "cant find the begin or end members" (from map class)

```
class Transition{

public:
    Transition():inNext(){};
    ~Transition(){};

    map<string, string>& getTransition(){
        return inNext;
    }

    void setTransition(string a, string b){

        inNext.insert(pair<string,string>(a,b));
    }

    void printTransition(Transition a){
        map <string, string>::iterator it;
        for(it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++){

            cout << (*it).first << ","<<(*it).second << endl;
        }

    }


private:
    map<string, string> inNext;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is weird: It's a member function *and* it takes another instance of `Transition` (and even **copies** it for no reason) as an argument. You probably want

```
void print() {
    // you want to print the content of the map inNext:
    for(map <string, string>::iterator it = inNext.begin(); it != inNext.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << "," << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

which is called like this:

```
Transition myTransition = ...;

myTransition.print();
```

Comment: you are right, i dont know what is happening with me today, that Transition was not needed there, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`begin` and `end` are members of `std::map` not of your class. You need to call `a.inNext.begin()` and `a.inNext.end()`.